# Undefined Reference to Doubly Linked List?

Tags: c++

Hey guys this is probably something really dumb that im looking over but I cant find out what I did wrong. This is the first time touched c++ in like 5 months so I feel really out of it... any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated, Thanks!.

Error Message

> testLL.o: In function `main`: testLL.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined
>   reference to `DblLink<int>::DblLink()` testLL.cpp:(.text+0x30):
>   undefined reference to `DblLink<int>::~DblLink()`
>   testLL.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to
>   `DblLink<int>::~DblLink()` testLL.o: In function
>   `menu(DblLink<int>&)': testLL.cpp:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference
>   to`DblLink::insert(int)`testLL.cpp:(.text+0x17e): undefined
>   reference to`DblLink::remove(int)`testLL.cpp:(.text+0x18c):
>   undefined reference to`DblLink::printIteratively()`

Heres  my code

```
//File: DblLink.h
// Doubly Linked list class with List Iterator class

#ifndef _DblLink_
#define _DblLink_ 
#include <assert.h>
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

// Prototype templace classes if they are to be friends
template <typename eltType> class DblLink;
template <typename eltType> class DblLinkItr;
template <typename eltType> class Node;


template <typename eltType> class DblLink{
    public:
        //Construct empty LinkedList
        DblLink();
        //Construct hard copy of another Linkedlist
        DblLink(DblLink&);

        //Destroy LinkedList
        ~DblLink();

        //Read string of strings into the list object
        //void readIntoList(string filename);

        //Assign another LinkedList to this LinkedList
        DblLink& operator=(const DblLink&);

        //Is the LinkedList empty?
        bool empty();

        bool find(eltType);

        //Ordered insert/remove 
        void insert(eltType);
        bool remove(eltType);

        //Print the Doubly Linked list iteratively
        void printIteratively();

        // Print the data recursively with a pointer
        //void printPtr(); 

        //Evaluate the Polynomial
        //virtual double operator()(double x) const;

    private:
        //linked list pointer
        Node<eltType>* head;

        //Get a copy of a (deep) node
        Node<eltType>* copy(Node<eltType> *);

        //Free nodes of the linked list
        void destroy(Node<eltType> *);

        //Need this to count nodes in LinkedList
        int countNodes(Node<eltType> *) const;

    //befriend double linked list iterator
    friend class DblLinkItr<eltType>;
    friend class Node<eltType>;

};

/******************************************************************************
 *******************************DblLink Iterator*******************************
 ******************************************************************************/

// Create an iterator to provide pointer to the doubly linked list
template <typename eltType> class DblLinkItr{

    public:
        //Construct a list iterator. 
        DblLinkItr(DblLink<eltType> &l);
        DblLinkItr(const DblLink<eltType> &l);

        //set curr to point at the first node of itr
        void start();
        // Is there more left before null?
        bool more();

        //Go to curr->next
        DblLinkItr operator++(int);

        //Get the value out of curr's node
        const eltType &operator*() const;

        eltType &operator*();

    private:
        const DblLink<eltType> &itr;
        Node<eltType> *curr;
};

#endif

    //File: DblLink.cpp
//Ordered Template Doubly Linked List Implementations

#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "DblLink.h"
#include "Node.h"

// Construct empty Linked List
template <typename eltType> DblLink<eltType>::DblLink() : head(NULL)
{}

//Copy constructor. copy() does the deep copy
template <typename eltType>
    DblLink<eltType>::DblLink(DblLink<eltType> &cl)
    {head = copy(cl.head);}

// Free all nodes   
template <typename eltType> DblLink<eltType>::~DblLink()
{destroy(head);}

//Assignment operator: copy() does the deep copy
template <typename eltType> DblLink<eltType>
    &DblLink<eltType>::operator=(const DblLink<eltType> &cl){
    if(this != &cl)
    {   
        destroy(head);
        head = copy(cl.head);
    }
    return *this;
}

//Is the LinkedList empty?
template <typename eltType> inline bool DblLink<eltType>::empty(){
    return(head == NULL);}

// Remove all nodes in the list starting at l-
template <typename eltType> void DblLink<eltType>::destroy(Node<eltType> *l)
        {
            Node<eltType> *doomed = l;
            l= l->next;
            delete doomed;
        }


// Deep copy. copy the source list l one node at a time
template <typename eltType>
    Node<eltType>* DblLink<eltType>::copy(Node<eltType> *l)
    {
        Node<eltType>* first=NULL; //ptr to beginning of copied List
        Node<eltType>* last=NULL; //ptr to last item insert in the copy
        if (l != NULL)
        {
            assert((first=last=new Node<eltType>(l->data,NULL,NULL)) != NULL);
            for (Node<eltType>* source=l->next; source!=NULL;
                            source=source->next,last=last->next)
                    {
                        last->next = new node<eltType>(source->data, last,NULL);
                        assert(last->next);
                    }
        }
    }

// Ordered Insert
template <typename eltType> 
        void DblLink<eltType>::insert(eltType x){
    //insert at head if new data is less than head or head is empty
    if (empty() || x < head->data)
        assert(head=new Node<eltType>(x,head,head));
    else
    {   Node<eltType>* p =head;
        // increment p while data is less than x and not equal to end of list
        while(p->data< x && p->next != NULL){
            p= p->next;

        //insert in middle of list
        if(p->data => x){
            Node<eltType>* new Node<eltType>(x, p->prev, p);
            p->prev->next =newNode;
            p->prev =newNode;
            }
        //insert at end of list
        if(p->next ==NULL){ 
            Node<eltType>* newNode = new Node<eltType>(x, p, NULL);
            p->next = newNode;
            }
        } 
    }
}

//Remove a node in an odered list
template <typename eltType>
        bool DblLink<eltType>::remove(eltType x){
    assert(!empty());
    Node<eltType>* p=head;
    Node<eltType>* trailp=NULL;
    //increment p and trail p while data is not equal to node or at end of list
    while (p != NULL &&p->data! = x)
    {
        trailp= p;
        p= p->next;
    }
    //if object is not found in the list
    if(p==NULL)
        return(false); // x is not in the list

    //if object is found at head of list
    else if(p == head){
        head->next->prev = NULL;
        head = head->next;
        delete p;
        return(true);
    }
    //if object is found in the middle of list
    else if(p->data == x && p->next !=NULL){
        trailp->next = p->next;
        p->next->prev = trailp;
        delete p;
        return(true);
    }
    //if object is found at end of list
    else{
        p->prev=NULL;
        trailp->next=NULL;
        delete p;
        return(true);
    }           

}

template <typename eltType>
    void DblLink<eltType>::printIteratively();
    {
        cout<< "Doubly Linked List printed Iteratively" <<endl;
        DblLinkItr<eltType> lt(l);
        for(lt.start(); lt.more(); lt++)
            cout << (*lt) << " ";

    }



/******************************************************************************
 *************************DblLink Iterator Implementations*********************
 ******************************************************************************/


//Create an iterator to provide interface for DblLink
template <typename eltType>
    DblLinkItr<eltType>::DblLinkItr(DblLink<eltType> &l): itr(l),curr(l.head)
    {} 

template <typename eltType>
    DblLinkItr<eltType>::DblLinkItr(const DblLink<eltType> &l): itr(l),curr(l.head)
    {}

//Set curr to point at itr's head
template <typename eltType>
    void DblLinkItr<eltType>::start(void)
    {curr= itr.head;}

//is curr at the end of the list?
template <typename eltType> 
    bool DblLinkItr<eltType>::more(void)
    {return curr != NULL;}

//Move curr to next node
template <typename eltType> 
    DblLinkItr<eltType> DblLinkItr<eltType>::operator++(int)
    {
        DblLinkItr <eltType> temp = *this;
        assert(curr != NULL);
        curr = curr->next;
        return(temp);
    }

//Return data in curr's node. 
template <typename eltType> eltType &DblLinkItr<eltType>::operator*()
{
    assert(curr !=NULL);
    return curr->data;
}

template <typename eltType> const eltType &DblLinkItr<eltType>::operator*() const
{
    assert(curr !=NULL);
    return curr->data;
}




/* Filename:       testLL.cpp                                   */
/* Purpose:        This program tests the DblLink class with a  */
/*                   menu-driven interface that permits the user*/
/*                   to perform a number of operations one or   */
/*           all of a Doubly Linked list of intergers   */
/****************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "DblLink.h"
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

/*********************************************************************/
/* Function name: menu                                               */
/* Description:   Displays menu, gets input from user, and carries   */
/*        out requested operation.               */ 
/* Parameters:    LinkedList<int>& Numbers - IMPORT/EXPORT -         */
/*          Object to store and interface with integers  */
/* Return Value:  None                                               */
/*********************************************************************/
void menu(DblLink<int>& Numbers);

/*********************************************************************/
/* Function name: choiceQuit                                         */
/* Description:   Confirms whether user wants to quit the program    */
/* Parameters:    None                                               */
/* Return Value:  bool                                               */
/*********************************************************************/
bool choiceQuit();

int main()
{
    DblLink<int> Numbers;

    menu(Numbers);
    return 0;
}


// Displays menu, gets input from user, and carries out requested operation.
void menu(DblLink<int>& Numbers)
{
    int menuChoice;
    bool quit=false;
    int userInput;

    do
     {
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"===================";
        cout<<"1. Insert";
        cout<<"2. Remove";
        cout<<"3. Print Foward";
        cout<<"4. Print";
        cout<<"5. Exit";
        cout<<"===================";
        cout<<"\n";
        cin>>menuChoice;
    switch(menuChoice)
     {
        case 1:
            cout<< "Enter a Number to insert into the list\n->";
            cin>> userInput;
            Numbers.insert(userInput);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<< "Enter a Number to remove from the list\n->";
            cin>> userInput;
            Numbers.remove(userInput);
            break;
        case 3:
            Numbers.printIteratively();
            break;
        case 4:

            break;

        case 5:
            quit=choiceQuit();
            break;
            default:
            cout<<"\nAn invalid choice was made, please try again.\n";
     }
    } while(quit==false);
}

// Confirms whether user wants to quit the program
bool choiceQuit()
{
  string confirm;
  cout<<"\nAre you sure you want to quit? (Yes/No)\n";
  cin>>confirm;
  while(confirm!="No"&&confirm!="no"&&confirm!="Yes"&&confirm!="yes")
    { cout<<"\nAre you sure you want to quit? (Yes/No)\n";
      cin>>confirm;
    }
  return(confirm!="No"&& confirm!="no");
}

// File: Node.h
// Doubly-linked list node definition/implementation

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

using namespace std;

// Need to prototype template classes if they are to be friends
template <class eltType> class DblLink;
template <class eltType> class DblLinkItr;

template <class eltType> class Node
{   private:
        Node(eltType info, Node *pLink = 0, Node *rLink=0) 
                   : data(info), prev(pLink), next(rLink) {};
        eltType data;
        Node*   prev; 
        Node*   next;
    friend class DblLink<eltType>;
    friend class DblLinkItr<eltType>;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Can't split header files and cpp files like that for templates. Kind of shitty, but see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Wow i would have never guessed haha, Thank you!